# How add image created in GD to template

Tags: php, gd, opentbs

I am looking for help with one problem. I would like to create an image using imageJpeg. And this image add to template using openTBS.

template:

```
[b.image;ope=changepic;from=[val];default=current;adjust]
```

php:

```
$TBS = $this->get('opentbs');
$TBS->NoErr = TRUE;
$TBS->LoadTemplate('template.odt', OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);
$image = imageCreate(300,200);
$colorRed = imageColorAllocate($image, 255,0,0);
$colorYellow = imageColorAllocate($image, 255,255,0);
imageFilledRectangle($image, 50, 50, 250, 150, $colorYellow);
$cccc=imageJpeg($image);
imageDestroy($image);
$data = array('image'=>$cccc);
$TBS->MergeField('b', $data);
$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD, 'file_name.odt');
```

However, image does not fit in the template sizes. After opening the file, only generated image is visible.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php), imageJpeg() creates the image and return a boolean.

So a nice solution is to use a temporary file :

```
...
$tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'tbs');
$cccc=imageJpeg($image, $tmp);
imageDestroy($image);
$data = array('image'=>$tmp);
$TBS->MergeField('b', $data);
$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD, 'file_name.odt');
```